# Django: jQuery autocomplete with multiple queryset

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to code an autocomplete for django which would display multiple queryset instead of a single list, an example of another site that have this implementation can be found here: https://www.uala.it/

Now i was able to send in a queryset the objects of two model:

```
def multi_autocomplete(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # In base a cosa sta scrivendo l'utente mostro un set di aziende.
        query = request.GET.get("term", "")
        companies = Company.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        treatments = Treatment.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        results = []
        for company in companies:
            place_json = company.name
            results.append(place_json)
        for treatment in treatments:
            place_json = treatment.name
            results.append(place_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    return HttpResponse(data, "application/json")
```

As you can see i'm returning the json.dumps with the data from the two models, how can I change the ui to show the values in different columns like in the link i provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge both list and send it in response

```
from django.db.models import F

def multi_autocomplete(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        query = request.GET.get("term", "")
        companies = Company.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).annotate(value=F('name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label')
        treatments = Treatment.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).annotate(value=F('name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label')
        results = list(companies) + list(treatments)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
```

Your autocomplete handler will look like.

```
$("#input_element_id").autocomplete({
     source: "{% url 'url name' %}",
     response: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.content.length) {
           var noResult = { value: "", label: "No data found" };
           ui.content.push(noResult);
         }
     },
     select: function (e, ui) {
         if (ui.item.value) {
            //do stuff after user selected option from autocomplete   
         }
     }
});
```

**Update**

Check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8es0vr2/) i think this will help.

Comment: The code you provided is working, and is the same result that i've already achieved, that is a single list with elements of both models... however i don't know how to output this result in two different lists.

Comment: exactly, like in the link i have provided: www.uala.it, in that site, if you try they display the results in two list: Trattamenti and Saloni. I don't know how to do something like that!

Comment: How to create one of the lists filtered on a related model (FK field)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the result in dictionary format and handle the same in autocomplete ajax response handler,

```
clist = []
tlist = []

for company in companies:
    clist.append(company.name)
for treatment in treatments:
    tlist.append(treatment)
data = json.dumps({"companies":clist, "treatments":tlist})
return HttpResponse(data, "application/json")
```

Autocomplete AJAX handling

```
$("#input_autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                cache:false,
                data:{
                    'term': request.term,
                },
                url: "{% url 'treatment-autocomplete' %}",
                success:function(data) {
                    $("#input_autocomplete").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                    $('#companyList').empty();
                    $('#treatmentList').empty();
                    $.each(data['companies'], function(i, item) {
                       $('#companyList').append(item);
                    });
                    $.each(data['treatments'], function(i, item) {
                       $('#treatmentList').append(item);
                    });
                }
           });

        },
        error: function(data) {
            $('#input_autocomplete').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');  
        }
         minLength: 1,
        open: function() {},
        close: function() {},
        focus: function(event,ui) {},
        select: function(event, ui) {}
```

});

Comment: What do you mean by "handle the same in autocomplete ajax response handler"? Can you show me some code for clarification? i am not that good with jquery, i actually have this in my html file: $(function() {
        $("#input_autocomplete").autocomplete({
          source: "{% url 'treatment-autocomplete' %}",
          minLength: 1,
        });
      });

Comment: do you want to display as shown in https://www.uala.it/ ??  you search in one autocomplete box and display the output in two other lists .

Comment: yes exaclty, however, I am not getting how to change the output in order to show it in two separated lists (in jQuery).